# How to hide SVG elements with JavaScript on a button click?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have tried doing that with this code:

```
svgElement.style.display = "none";
```

but it didn't work. How is it possible to do it with `getElementById`?

Comment: give your svgElement an unique id and call that id?

Comment: what is the code for calling this id?

Comment: document.getElementById("rect").what? = what?;

Comment: .style += "display:none;"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105895/hide-svg-elements-with-javascript

Comment: what is the function name?

Comment: function setColor(color)
{
    document.getElementById("rect").style.display = "none";
}

Comment: I have this code ^ I want it instead of changing the colour of the element, make it disappear.

Comment: Last thing is to place graphic inside div and hide this div.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the style property `display` and set it to `none`

```js
function hideSVG() {
  var style = document.getElementById("myRect").style.display;
  if(style === "none")
    document.getElementById("myRect").style.display = "block";
  else
    document.getElementById("myRect").style.display = "none";
  //or to hide the all svg
  //document.getElementById("mySvg").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<svg id="mySvg">
  <rect id="myRect" fill="red" width="100px" height="100px"></rect>
</svg>
<button onclick="hideSVG()">Hide/Show</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked with me. How can I show the item again?

Comment: It is only hide. Can you please add the show code for the same id.

Comment: Run the code snippet and you will show the `Hide/Show` button. Click on it once and it will hide the rectangle. Click on it again and it will show it

Comment: Yeap. Saw it. How can I do that for several objects? because when I assign the same ID for the other objects it doesn't work cuz the ID has to be unique but I want to do it for several objects at the same time.

Comment: If they are all in the same SVG you can use the SVG id. Or use the same classe for each object

Comment: But this is another question different from the one you asked. You should ask another question in SO and you will have your answer

Comment: it didn't work when I used the SVG id. This is the objects that I am trying to show/hide

Comment: <path id="Myrect" clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#A00202" d="M101.5,206c0,0-5.1-13.4-6.5-24.6c0,0-22.9,3.1-23,3.1c-0.1,0,1,16.6,7.8,31.4
   L101.5,206z"/>

  <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#A00202" d="M155.8,62.3c0,0,12.2-7,22.9-10c0,0-6.4-22.5-6.4-22.6
   c0-0.1-15.9,3.3-29.2,12.3L155.8,62.3z"/>
  <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#A00202" d="M119,90.8c0,0,8.5-10.5,17.1-17c0,0-13.4-17.5-13.4-17.6
   c0-0.1-13.1,8.6-22,21.2L119,90.8z"/>

Comment: Sure, will ask another question. Thanks for your help:)